# Update multiple tables from query result

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to update multiple tables from a query result?

I've tried using a cursor. But it's still not working.

Here's the code :

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT TABLE_NAME  
     FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE column_name = 'Code1';

OPEN db_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    UPDATE @TableName 
    SET Code1 = Code + '_' + Type

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: A DML statement can only effect one table at a time; if that's what you're asking.  You *can* use things like instead of triggers to give the "illusion" of updating multiple tables (like when you perform an `UPDATE` on a `VIEW`), however, within the trigger only one table at a time would actually be updated per DML statement in that trigger. You can't have things like `UPDATE Table1, Table2 SET IsActive = 0 WHERE ID = 1;` and expect rows in both `Table1` and `Table2` to be updated.

Comment: You example shows updating of a single table. Provide an example of wanting to update multiple tables at once.

Comment: @Greg What OP is trying to achieve is to create dynamic SQL for UPDATE-ing all tables in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hypothesis

I suppose that OP is trying to dynamically build and execute SQL-code for all tables that have column `Code1`

### Solution

Solution (one of many) could be:

1. Build cursor of created SQL-expressions
2. In cycle `exec` created expressions

### Example code

```
DECLARE @sql_code varchar(max)

DECLARE code_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT 
       'UPDATE '+ TABLE_NAME + ' SET Code1= Code + ''_'' + Type;' AS SQL_CODE
     FROM 
         information_schema.columns -- WHERE column_name = 'Code1';

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @sql_code

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    exec(@sql_code)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

### Caution

I did not tested it (of cause - I don't have similar DB) - so be careful.

### Update

It's even simpler would be to modify OP code like this:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
FOR SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME   -- note DISTINCT here
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'Code1'; 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
EXEC('UPDATE '+ @TableName + ' SET Code1 = Code + ''_'' + Type') -- note EXEC here

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: If you have [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - you can do even simpler: build in one SQL statement **all** `UPDATE`-s and `EXEC` it. Everything could be done in one `EXEC(SELECT STRING_AGG('UPDATE '+ TABLE_NAME + ' SET Code1= Code + ''_'' + Type;', '\n').. )`  expression.